# in k_rem_pio2 file function is there any number which not hold carry!=0 for ih==2 case?

Tags: java, c, windows, linux, ieee-754

I'm working on application using the math computation. For my code I need to know how to cover all paths of code of libraries I'm using. The one of not covered yet is in `k_rem_pio2`  file. The kernel function have branch for `ih==2` numbers and then ther is an

```
if(carry!=0) -z= scalbn(one,q0);
```

My question is, for what number the if condition is not met ... I assume that the only case would be number with `iq[i] = 0` for all `i < jz` (I'm working with prec = 2),  but which number can have `iq[i] = 0`?

Comment: wanna add some code example with which we can try to help you?